# Test Class error while having an OrderItem into it

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class

Hi I am trying to have an orderitem into my test class in order to test a trigger.

class is : `

```
public static testmethod void TaskTrigger_Test1()
    {
          Account a = new Account(`enter preformatted text here`Name = 'Test');
        insert a;

            Order o = new Order(name='Test1',AccountId=a.id,EffectiveDate=system.today(),status='draft');
            insert o;

            OrderItem oi = new OrderItem(OrderId=o.id,Quantity='decimal.valueof('1')',PricebookEntryId='test');
            insert oi;


        Task t = new Task(whatid=o.id,Priority = 'normal',status='open',subject='Email:xxxx');
        insert t;

        system.assertequals('Sent',o.status);
     }
   }
```

but I get this error. Any ideas?

Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found '1' at line 33 column 81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the single quote for
 Quantity =  decimal.valueof('1')
if not try passing Quantity =1 (internally already its decimal placess are defined)

OrderItem oi = new OrderItem(OrderId=o.id,Quantity='decimal.valueof('1')',PricebookEntryId='test');
            insert oi;